# datediff and Excel not matching

Tags: r, date, openxlsx

Any ideas why R is adding 2 days to an Excel date?

Details:
I am importing an Excel file with openxlx using the code:

```
wb.temp <- loadWorkbook(filename)
data.import <- read.xlsx (wb.temp, sheet = 1, startRow = 3, colNames = TRUE, na.strings = "NA", detectDates = FALSE)
```

(detectDates = TRUE gives an error although all dates in the XLSX look ok)

The xlsx files had some values for the field Event_Date of "2022-02-0**7**"

- R imported these dates as 4459**9**

However, when I ran the following r-code to convert these dates to yyyy-mm-dd:

```
data.import$Event_Date <- as.Date(import.temp$Event_Date, origin = '1900-01-01')
```

data.import$Event_Date took the value of "2022-02-0**9**" when inputting  44599

As a check:

- difftime("2022-02-07","1900-01-01") yields 4459**7**

So, why R is adding 2 days to an Excel date during the data import?

thanks

bob

Comment: It should be `origin = '1899-12-30'`.

Comment: The is a known bug with Excel with regards to Feb 29, 1900.  This day did not exist but Excel does.  Also, in Excel Jan 1, 1900 is day 1 while R assumes it to be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks much; I found another solution.

Instead of using the R `as.date`, the `xlsx::convertToDate` solves it using:

```
data.temp$Event_Date <- openxlsx::convertToDate(data.temp$Event_Date, origin = '1900-01-01')
```

https://rdrr.io/cran/openxlsx/man/convertToDate.html